# Sort array and its object key in alphabetical order in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array in the following format. I have sorted the array in alphabetical order.But every element in the array, a sub array exist. I would like to sort them in alphabetical order too.

```
var myObj = [
{
    "name":"John",
    "items": [
        { "id":1, "car":"maruti" },  
        { "id":2, "car":"wolks" },
        { "id":3, "car":"bmw" }            
    ]
},
{
    "name":"Peter",
    "items": [
        { "id":4, "car":"alto" },  
        { "id":5, "car":"swift" },                          
    ]
}];
```

This is the code I have used to sort the main array. Here I would like to sort the 'items' array in alphabetical order.

```
myObj.sort(function(a, b) {
     var nameA=a.name.toLowerCase(), nameB=b.name.toLowerCase();          
     if (nameA < nameB) {
         return -1
     }
     if (nameA > nameB){
         return 1
     }
     return 0 
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't feel right to do anything in a `sort` function *other* than sort the immediate items in the array - I'd iterate twice, once to sort the `myObj`, and once to sort each `items` property.

You can also use `localeCompare` to simplify your code:

```js
var myObj=[{"name":"John","items":[{"id":1,"car":"maruti"},{"id":2,"car":"wolks"},{"id":3,"car":"bmw"}]},{"name":"Peter","items":[{"id":4,"car":"alto"},{"id":5,"car":"swift"},]}]
myObj.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name));
myObj.forEach(({ items }) => items.sort((a, b) => a.car.localeCompare(b.car)));
console.log(myObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through all objects in array. You can use map function for that and sort each items list with a sort function.

```js
var myObj = [
          {
          "name":"John",
          "items": [
              { "id":1, "car":"maruti" },  
              { "id":2, "car":"wolks" },
              { "id":3, "car":"bmw" }            
          ]},
          {
            "name":"Peter",
          "items": [
              { "id":4, "car":"alto" },  
              { "id":5, "car":"swift" },                          
          ]
       }
      ];
function sorting(a, b){
    // you can use just 
    // return a.car.localeCompare(b.car)  
    // reference CertainPerformance answer
    var nameA=a.car.toLowerCase(), nameB=b.car.toLowerCase();          
    if (nameA < nameB) {
      return -1
    }
    if (nameA > nameB){
      return 1
    }
    return 0 
}
myObj.forEach(obj => obj.items.sort(sorting))
console.log(myObj)
// myObj.map(obj => obj.items.sort(sorting)) // returns new array
// updated answer for useful comments.
```

Comment: Use `forEach` instead of `map` if you're not returning a new array.

Comment: @Barmar is right. `map` has very specific purpose: create new array with "mapped" items. It is not intented to do side-effects. There is `forEach` for that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over the array and then sort `items` of each object.

```js
var myObj = [{"name":"John","items":[{"id":1,"car":"maruti"},{"id":2,"car":"wolks"},{"id":3,"car":"bmw"}]},{"name":"Peter","items":[{"id":4,"car":"alto"},{"id":5,"car":"swift"},]}];
      
myObj.forEach(({items}) => items.sort((a,b) => a.car.localeCompare(b.car)));
console.log(myObj);
```