# How to list options in an alphabetical order vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js

How to list the options in an alphabetical order.I am running a quiz app from the code [here](https://codeburst.io/create-a-quiz-with-vue-js-ed1e8e0e8294).I need to list the responses in a alphabetical order. How do I do that?

Below is the list of questions that is sent to the template

**Reponse**

```
var quiz = {

    title: 'My quiz',

    questions: [

      {

        text: "Question 1",

        responses: [

          {text: 'Wrong, too bad.'}, 

          {text: 'Right!', correct: true}, 

        ]

      }, {

        text: "Question 2",

        responses: [

          {text: 'Right answer', correct: true}, 

          {text: 'Wrong answer'}, 

        ]

      } 

    ]

  };
```

I am trying to use filters

```
  Vue.filter('myMapping',function(index){
  mapping = ["A", "B", "C" , "D", "E"];
      return mapping[index];
  });


   <div class="ques_block" v-for="(question, index) in quiz.questions">

    <div v-show="index === questionIndex">
        <h3>{{index + 1}}) {{question.text}}</h3>
            <div class="option_div" v-for="(response,resp) in question.responses">
                <input type="radio" v-bind:name="index"  v-bind:value="response.correct"  v-model="userResponses[index]"/>
                <label> {{resp| myMapping}})  {{response.text}} </label>
            </div>
                        </div>
                       </div>
```

[Jsfiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/Bl_praveen2004/7Lm69peh/1/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort array and its object key in alphabetical order in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50637659/sort-array-and-its-object-key-in-alphabetical-order-in-javascript)

Comment: This sounds like more of a javascript problem than a vue.js problem. Why not just sort the array before you display it?

Comment: How to do that and I need to display the correct answer in the answer_block with Alphabhetical

Comment: Check @FirstIndex answer

Comment: @FirstIndex I need to do this in a vue.js. I have pasted the code using filters I tried to acheive the same results

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a javascript problem than a vuejs problem. You would want to sort the array before displaying it.

after declaring the array you can run this sort snippet.

```
quiz.questions.sort((a, b) => a.text.localeCompare(b.text));
quiz.questions.forEach(({ responses }) => responses.sort((a, b) => a.text.localeCompare(b.text)));
```

What this does is to sort the outer "object" while using the key (text) in ascending order, once the outer object has been sorted, you loop through the responses array inside the object to sort each object using the key(text) in ascending order.